# How Do We Create a Scrollable Column in Bootstrap 4, With Content Staying Within the Viewport?

Tags: bootstrap-4

What I want is a two-pane presentation, with a list of items on the left and content on the right. The overall page height should fill the viewport. The list will have more content than can fit in the viewport, though, so it should scroll vertically.

[This page](https://klassbook.commonsware.com/playlists/test.html) shows what I want... except that it has a height pinned to `800px`, whereas I would like it to fill the viewport. My basic structure there is:

```
<body class="d-flex" style="padding: 4px;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3" style="height: 800px; overflow-y: scroll;">
                <nav class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
// whole lotta <a> tags
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <iframe id="klassbook" width="100%" height="100%" class="embed-responsive-item" src="/lessons/Hello World/function.html"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

// script stuff

</body>
```

[This page](https://klassbook.commonsware.com/playlists/test-percent.html) is the same content, except that I switch `height: 800px;` on the left column `<div>` to `height: 100%;`. This has the whole page be scrollable, causing the `<iframe>` to expand past the bottom of the viewport.

[This page](https://klassbook.commonsware.com/playlists/test-percent-row.html) is the same content, except that I move the `height: 100%;` to the row `<div>`. It gives me the same visual effect as the preceding one.

What is the recipe for this sort of two-pane UI, where the right side fills available space and the left side scrolls?

Comment: https://klassbook.commonsware.com/playlists/test.html You are wanting this in desktop and mobile also??

Comment: @MrPerfectionist: I am focusing on desktops and large tablets for this page, not phones.

Comment: overflow-y: scroll;
    max-height: 100vh;
    display: list-item;

Comment: Oooo... that helps a ton! That gives me [this page](https://klassbook.commonsware.com/playlists/test-mr-p-1.html). Would you like to write that up as an answer, or should I? Thanks!

Comment: Given answer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your left `div`

```
overflow-y: scroll; 
max-height: 100vh; 
display: list-item;
```